# How to get output of variable with line breaks?

Tags: bash, variable, top, subshell

I want to get onre output of top to variable for future processing. I tried:

```
top=$(top -n1)
top=$(top -n1 -w80)
top=$(top -n1 -b -w80)
top=$(COLUMNS=100 top -b-n1)
```

When I run `echo $top` then I see something like on the screenshot
[image]
that is `top` output completely without line breaks. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output are you looking to capture?

Comment: Related: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Related: `uptime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Double-quote the variable

try `echo "${top}"` after assigning `top="$(top -n1)"`

Answer (score 0):

Unable to replicate:

```
$ t="$( top -b -n1 )"
$ echo "$t" | head -n3
top - 14:49:52 up 243 days, 17:18,  2 users,  load average: 0.03, 0.07, 0.12
Tasks: 205 total,   1 running, 203 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.4 us,  0.5 sy,  0.1 ni, 96.4 id,  0.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

Comment: I think he is seeing the same thing as you based on his screenshot.  I'm guessing he only wants the top line?

Comment: The difference is that in the OP's screen capture, there are no linebreaks.  I am unable to replicate this.

Comment: I can replicate that on centos 7.  As Andrew pointed out in his answer, the variable must be quoted or it prints as a single line.