# Is it possible to keep variable in multiple lines?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Sample file

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat file.txt 
Apples
Bananas
Cherries
Dragon Fruit
Elderberry
wolf@linux:~$
```

grep `s` from the `file.txt`

```
wolf@linux:~$ grep s file.txt 
Apples
Bananas
Cherries
wolf@linux:~$
```

Keep it in `var`

```
wolf@linux:~$ var=`grep s file.txt`
wolf@linux:~$ echo $var 
Apples Bananas Cherries
wolf@linux:~$
```

Instead of keeping it in horizontal lines like `Apples Bananas Cherries`, would it be possible to keep data in variable similar to their original format?

**Updating the answer and example for future reference**

[Always use double quotes around variable substitutions and command substitutions: "$foo", "$(foo)"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/409008)

E.g.

Without double quote

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo $var
Apples Bananas Cherries
wolf@linux:~$
```

With double quote

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo "$var"
Apples
Bananas
Cherries
wolf@linux:~$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get output of variable with line breaks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404859/how-to-get-output-of-variable-with-line-breaks) and also see more in-depth explanation: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters?noredirect=1&lq=1, especially the part **Why do I need to write `"$foo"`? What happens without the quotes?**